# SQL - Add query parameter with join

Tags: sql, postgresql

There're 3 tables. Is it possible by **Persons.Id** to get not only the **city** person lives in but also all the **cities** all her/his **friends** live in?

Eg for person with Id = 1 we get 2 items: Paris(he lives in) and New York(his friend Michele lives in)

Is it possible to make it one query using PostreSQL?

**Persons**

```
Id   Name     CityId
1    Mike     2
2    Bred     3
3    Michele  3
```

**FriendsConnections**

```
Id   Person1  Person2
1    1        3
2    2        3
```

**Cities**

```
Id  Title
1   London
2   Paris
3   New York
```

Comment: Please show us the result that you expect. For a given person, do you want one record, or several?

Comment: Several. For person with id = 2 I need to get 2 cities: Paris, New York

Comment: For id = 2, you'll only get 1 result: New York, since both Bred and Michele live in New York.
I guess you meant for id = 1, you'll get Paris and New York.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-- Get the city for Person 2
select c.Title
from Persons p
inner join Cities c on p.CityId = c.Id
where p.Id = 2
union 
-- Get the friends cities for Person 2
select c.Title
from Persons p1
inner join FriendsConnections fc on p1.id = fc.Person1
inner join Persons p2 on fc.Person2 = p2.id
inner join Cities c on p2.CityId = c.Id
where p1.Id = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
SELECT
    Persons.Name        AS Name,
    Cities.Title        AS City,
    Friends.Name        AS Friend,
    FriendsCities.Title AS FriendsCity
FROM Persons
-- Join the friends
LEFT JOIN FriendsConnections
    ON FriendsConnections.Person1 = Persons.Id
    OR FriendsConnections.Person2 = Persons.Id
LEFT JOIN Persons AS Friends
    ON (Friends.Id = FriendsConnections.Person1
    OR Friends.Id = FriendsConnections.Person2)
    AND Friends.Id != Persons.Id
-- Join the city
LEFT JOIN Cities
    ON Cities.Id = Persons.CityId
-- Join the friends' cities
LEFT JOIN Cities AS FriendsCities
    ON FriendsCities.Id = Friends.CityId
```

Maybe you prefer this one:

```
SELECT
    Friend1.Name AS Friend1,
    City1.Title  AS City1,
    Friend2.Name AS Friend2,
    City2.Title  AS City2
FROM FriendsConnections
-- Join the friends
LEFT JOIN Persons AS Friend1
    ON Friend1.Id = FriendsConnections.Person1
LEFT JOIN Persons AS Friend2
    ON Friend2.Id = FriendsConnections.Person2
-- Join the cities
LEFT JOIN Cities AS City1
    ON City1.Id = Friend1.CityId
LEFT JOIN Cities AS City2
    ON City2.Id = Friend2.CityId
```

You can maybe change the `JOIN` type, depending on the foreign keys you have.

Answer (score 0):

So Michel is friend of Mike and Bred, and lives in New York, Mike lives in paris and Bred in New York.

I Believe you expect a result such as:

> Name | CityName | FriendName | FriendCityName
>
> Mike | Paris | Michel | New York
>
> Bred | New York | Michel | New York

The SQL code valid for any relational database should be as follow:

```
SELECT p.name, pc.title as PersonCity, f.name as FriendName, fc.title as FriendCity 
FROM Persons p
-- Getting all persons friends (one to many)
INNER JOIN FriendsConnections f
ON f.person1 = p.id
-- Getting all persons cities (one to one)
INNER JOIN Cities pc
ON pc.id = f.person1
-- Getting all friend cities (one to one)
INNER JOIN Cities fc
ON fc.id = f.person2
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned to wanted to get a `list` of cities, the following query should work:

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=4abcbb33ed03506d32a39d17555a4b5d)**

```
select c.title city
from persons p
inner join
(
  select id, cityid
  from persons
   union
  select pm.id, pf.cityid
  from persons pm
  inner join friendsconnections fc on fc.person1 = pm.id
  inner join persons pf on pf.id = fc.person2
   union
  select pm.id, pf.cityid
  from persons pm
  inner join friendsconnections fc on fc.person2 = pm.id
  inner join persons pf on pf.id = fc.person1
) p_to_c on p_to_c.id = p.id
left join cities c on c.id = p_to_c.cityid
where p.id = 1;
```

Result:

```
city
--------
New York
Paris
```

Answer (score 0):

Following query will give you the expected output.

```
select name,city,friend,D.title as friendCity from 
(select A.name as name,C.title as city,B.cityid as friendcityid,B.name as friend from persons A join 
(select * from friendsconnections join persons on friendsconnections.person2=persons.id)
B on A.id=B.person1
join cities C on A.cityid=C.id
)tmp
join cities D on tmp.friendcityid=D.id
```

Output

```
name  city       friend   friendCity
Mike  Paris      Michele  New York
Bred  New York   Michele  New York
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `exists` or `in` for the matching.  That is, the outer select is only on `cities` -- that way, you don't need to incur overhead to remove duplicates:

```
select c.*
from cities c
where exists (select p.cityId
              from persons p 
              where p.id = 1 and c.id = p.cityId
             ) or
      exists (select p.cityId
              from persons p join
                   FriendsConnections fc
                   on p.id = fc.person2
              where fc.person1 = 1 and c.id = p.cityId
             );
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9487bb95b5ce766e71de4d905e5f12b1) is a db<>fiddle.